# Is there a way to get an actual random distribution from a seed in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I need to get random numbers, but I need the same results every time I run the code. Normally, this would mean using a seed, but as far as I can tell, SQL's RAND function uses the formula:

```
RAND(@Seed) = 0.00001863297* @Seed + 0.71357336
```

with the integers truncated off which is, you know, not particularly random. 
[Here's a chart I made of it because I couldn't quite believe it myself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvExY.png).

This was made with the code:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1;

CREATE TABLE #Test ( 
         seed  int
       , ran float);

WHILE @i < 10000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Test
           ( seed
           , ran) 
    SELECT @i*23
         , Rand(@i*23)

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;
```

Anyway, is there a way to generate real random numbers off of a seed in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

you can use newid() and rand as below

```
select convert(int,rand(convert(varbinary,newid()))*@seed)
```

Random number insertion of 10000 numbers instead of while loop

```
insert into #test
select top (10000)  seed = row_number() over (order by (select null))
        ,ran = convert(int,rand(convert(varbinary,newid()))*10000)
        from master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
```

Comment: That won't get the same result each time it's called with the same seed

Comment: you need same results?

Comment: The term "seed" should help you. Technically, the computer clock is a seed, too, but lets ignore that for now. ;)

Comment: @Evan if you want to guarantee the same results, perhaps you could use this answer to store the results in a permanent table instead of a temp. You run the SQL once to populate the table, and then just refer to the table each time you need the random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the point of the seed.

You only use the seed argument for the *first* call to `RAND()`.  The subsequent calls should not use the argument.

Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql).

> Repetitive calls of RAND() with the same seed value return the same results.
>   For one connection, if RAND() is called with a specified seed value, all subsequent calls of RAND() produce results based on the seeded RAND() call.

The example shown, `SELECT RAND(100), RAND(), RAND()`,   will always return the same result.

Comment: While the facts in your answer is correct, I think the OP's asking about randomness of SQLServer's RAND(). Quoting from the question, "with the integers truncated off which is, you know, not particularly random.".